# Water backup on new double vanity/both sides

Tags: vanity

Installed new double vanity. Water drains slowly on right side and backing up in sink on left side. Didn't have to do anything to p trap lines up same as old vanity. Did have trouble with stoppers when installing. Could stoppers be the problem?

Comment: What was the problem with the stoppers? Can you provide pictures of the stoppers and the piping under the sink?

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I'm **"Picturing"** (hint-hint) that you have a **Regular T** which has both drains aligned with each other & gravity's supposed to drop the water down the drain that's perfectly in the middle of both sinks. Like this.
[image: Bad]
 This might be what was previously there & was fine. But, did you change anything like the vertical heights of anything? However, this is actually the wrong setup & allows for a lot of debris build-up & sometimes very poor draining.

-

The correct setup is to actually connect to the P-trap off to one side & straight down from one of the sinks. Then you turn your T side ways (but preferably a WYE fitting...see last picture) to accept a long pipe from the other sink.
[image: Good]

-

Here's the best setup, using a WYE. See how the fitting starts the gravity drop.
[image: Best]

-

Anyway, I do realize this is likely an Off-The-Shelf Kit & you won't be doing any of the above permanent type of setups. But, stoppers shouldn't be the problem if water's normally exiting the sink. I would take another look around the store & ask about other or better double sink kits. Or, even see if they can help you screw one together of individual parts.

I think you just need to either match exactly what you had before or get a better kit & even a different kit if another setup can work under your sinks. I have run into your problem a number of times before & it was completely remedied by the 2 offset setups above.