# New bathroom double vanity. One sink runs the other backs up and drains slow

Tags: plumbing, drain

[image]

So when I run either sink for a minute the other fills and they both drain slow. Is it the trap height and/or a clog in the old line or something else. Noob here n looking for help. Thanks

Comment: Seems like a straight-forward clog to me, either in the drain or the vent. Have you investigated?

Comment: Once I find the snake. The best part of owning tools is looking for them

Comment: That setup isn't terrible, but it is odd. Take a level and make sure both pipes slope down to the tee. It might just be the picture, but it looks like it's level across both pipes, with a slight tilt downward to the left sink

Comment: The answer from Iggy in this previous post is the correct answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/85293/water-backup-on-new-double-vanity-both-sides

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll try the plumbing now. It makes more sense

Comment: But I want it to be a clog

Comment: Anyone else troubled by the single sanitary tee in the middle?  It clearly favors the left side. A double sanitary tee (with a clean-out or capped top) seems more suitable. ( I know this post is  old, but it is still referenced.)